# What is the free list (that PyDict_ClearFreeList refers to)?

Tags: python, dictionary, python-c-api, python-internals

There is a C API function for Python dictionaries called [`PyDict_ClearFreeList`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/dict.html#c.PyDict_ClearFreeList). However the docstring is rather sparse:

> `int PyDict_ClearFreeList()`
>
> Clear the free list. Return the total number of freed items.
>
> New in version 3.3.

This function has no parameters so it (probably) has nothing to do with any specific dictionary.

And it returns an `int`. This seems rather weird because that indicates it refers to some C state because python "classes" always have a `Py_ssize_t` size.

So what exactly is this "free list"?

Comment: Are you vaguely familiar with the dictobject.c source?  https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/dictobject.c Don't worry if you aren't a C expert.  You can learn quite a lot about how dicts work just from the comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that the free list has nothing to do with any specific dictionary; in fact, it applies to numerous data types (e.g. [`PyFloat_ClearFreeList`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/float.html#c.PyFloat_ClearFreeList)).

The free list is where Python keeps the list of the free places it could put things - i.e. memory containing objects it is no longer using, but which it hasn't released back to the global Python memory pool or the system.

Per [this useful Theano tutorial](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/python-memory-management.html#internal-memory-management):

> To speed-up memory allocation (and reuse) Python uses a number of
>   lists for small objects. Each list will contain objects of similar
>   size: there will be a list for objects 1 to 8 bytes in size, one for 9
>   to 16, etc. When a small object needs to be created, either we reuse a
>   free block in the list, or we allocate a new one.